# Function output by parameter - value relations

Tags: functions, parameter-estimation

I have a parameter set, `P`; `p1`, `p2` ... `pn`

And also I have value set V; `v1`, `v2` ... `vm`

Suppose each of my parameter takes value between in an fixed number interval, for example 0-5, and I can provide relation of increase or decrease in each parameter to each value.

For example, lets say for p1,

```
 an increase in p1 increases v1 and v5

 a decrease in p1 decreases v1, v3 and v5

 no change in rest of them.
```

Also I have parameter relative importance, i.e, p1 is more important than p2, p2 is more important than p3 etc.

With this information, I want to get a distribution of v1,...,vm values by percentage to total V when I give p1, ..., pn.

For example, I want an output like;

```
 v1: %30

 v2: %12

 .....

 vm: %3
```

My question is, is there a method for this? How can I get V value percentages when I provide P parameter values?